# keep gnome fallback, drop everything else

Tags: gnome, gnome-classic

I've been on 13.04 since alpha and have gotten really used to gnome fallback with compiz again (it wasn't as well evolved when I switched to Gnome shell in the first place). I have set this up the way I like and am now afraid of the next or second next update dropping beloved fallback mode.

Moving forward, what are my best options in your eyes? Never update gnome from now on? Set up MATE, make friends with slower GNOME 3 classic look or the cinnamon equivalent, tweak XFCE to suit my expectations? Can I somehow keep GNOME fallback as an autonomous desktop and get rid of gnome 3 shell and cinnamon (without dropping nemo preferably)?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: This debate has raged ever since gnome 3 was released. Only you can decide for yourself. Personally I find I prefer kde these days. I have a good friend who swears by Fedora 7 (way beyond EOL). Only time will tell if MATE can be maintained moving forwards.

Answer (score 0):

if you are fine with making friends with gnome 3, Ubuntu has released a Ubuntu/gnome OS. their are instructions for switching to this [flavor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME/ReleaseNotes/12.10flavor) here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the 'fallback' mode you're probably best to find a different DE. It's never a good idea to hold-back updates just for the old environment. Sooner or later you will want to install applications that conflict with the library versions you have installed.

As of Gnome 3.8, they have removed the fallback mode. They have added [Gnome Classic mode](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2032800/gnome-3-8-delivers-more-privacy-and-a-new-classic-mode.html) which used the Gnome 3 shell and some extensions to accomplish pretty close to the original look you're after. Ubuntu 13.04 (and even [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.org) 13.04) will ship with Gnome 3.6 which does not contain the new classic mode. However the [Gnome3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) will allow upgrades to some parts of 3.8, though at this point Classic mode is not among them. There are additionally the staging and testing PPAs which can be added which do introduce that functionality but also introduce less stability.